# How to find unique URL's to specific pages within a website

Tags: forms, url

I am building an online portal for a client. I am in no way a professional coder/site builder, but do have some knowledge and experience with HTML and site building. The client owns multiple entities/companies in Delaware. The Delaware website has a site where you can search for these entities and it brings up a unique information page for each entity (https://icis.corp.delaware.gov/Ecorp/EntitySearch/NameSearch.aspx). In my portal I am trying to get an entity specific URL for each entity. Unfortunately, the URL in the address bar stays the same and doesn't show the unique URL for each entity.

Is there a way to find where in the inspect element or view page source where I can find the unique URL for a specific entity? So lets say I search for entity file number 5549973...when that page comes up, is there a way to find the link that would allow me to point to that specific page of information without having to go through the search again?

Comment: The client is not a government business. My client just uses the Delaware state site as a resource to look up information about companies they own. I am trying to take a step out of the process by finding the direct URL for each of their entities (there is about 30 of them) instead of having to search for each one each time they need the information.

Comment: What you want to do isn't possible with the way that icis.corp.delaware.gov is built. There is not any kind of unique URL for each of those entities.

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the answer, but feared that it was...thanks!